# What would be a good approach to creating this range of array of arrays in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this array I'm creating for a select box; however, this definitely does not look like a clean way of going about it. Can anyone provide an easier way to write this out?

```
[ [ '0', '0' ],
  [ '1', '1' ],
  [ '2', '2' ],
  [ '3', '3' ],
  [ '4', '4' ],
  [ '5', '5' ],
  [ '6', '6' ],
  [ '7', '7' ],
  [ '8', '8' ],
  [ '9', '9' ],
  [ '10', '10' ],
  [ '11', '11' ],
  [ '12', '12' ],
  [ '13', '13' ],
  [ '14', '14' ],
  [ '15', '15' ],
  [ '16', '16' ],
  [ '17', '17' ],
  [ '18', '18' ],
  [ '19', '19' ],
  [ '20', '20' ],
  [ '21', '21' ],
  [ '22', '22' ],
  [ '23', '23' ] ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question we expect to see evidence of your effort, either in where you searched and what those failed to show you, or your code toward solving the problem. As is it looks like you want us to write code for you which is not what Stack Overflow is for. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]", http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Array.new(24){|i| [i.to_s, i.to_s]}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed because it includes the 0 and stringify's the integers. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyGaeta modifying @sawa's answer, try: `('0'..'23').map{|i| [i, i] }`.